# Intellij Android Support plugin exception on project creation

Tags: android, intellij-idea

On Intellij CE 2018.3.5, using bundled Android Support plugin, I got this exception when trying to create an Android project. I used default options suggested by the wizard.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Project 'SomeDir/MyApplication' My Application; Disposed: false; Open: false
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.DocumentCommitThread.commitSynchronously(DocumentCommitThread.java:348)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiDocumentManagerBase.lambda$doCommit$2(PsiDocumentManagerBase.java:443)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1057)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiDocumentManagerBase.doCommit(PsiDocumentManagerBase.java:451)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiDocumentManagerBase.commitDocument(PsiDocumentManagerBase.java:290)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiDocumentManagerBase.commitAllDocuments(PsiDocumentManagerBase.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.invokeAndWait(ApplicationImpl.java:670)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.invokeAndWait(ApplicationImpl.java:683)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.render(Template.java:255)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.project.NewProjectModel$ProjectTemplateRenderer.performCreateProject(NewProjectModel.java:296)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.project.NewProjectModel$ProjectTemplateRenderer.render(NewProjectModel.java:253)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.template.MultiTemplateRenderer.countDown(MultiTemplateRenderer.java:64)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.template.MultiTemplateRenderer.skipRender(MultiTemplateRenderer.java:82)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.template.RenderTemplateModel.handleSkipped(RenderTemplateModel.java:190)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.handleFinished(ModelWizard.java:409)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.goForward(ModelWizard.java:331)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.ideahost.IdeaWizardAdapter.doNextAction(IdeaWizardAdapter.java:88)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.ideahost.AndroidModuleBuilder.doNextAction(AndroidModuleBuilder.java:139)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.newProjectWizard.AbstractProjectWizard.doNextAction(AbstractProjectWizard.java:246)
    at com.intellij.ide.wizard.AbstractWizard$5.actionPerformed(AbstractWizard.java:208)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    ...
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:719)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:668)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:363)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I'm wondering any one has faced this before? Is there any way to get around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. On my IntelliJ, I have installed **HaskForce** plugin for Haskell support. Once I disabled it, the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200816). Please follow it for updates and provide more details so that JetBrains developers can reproduce it.